# Spring/Hibernate - validating groups manually and return a BindingResult

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I want to manually validate (not using @Valid or @Validated) using groups and return a BindingResult.

I have a spring validator configured

```
  <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" >
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
  </bean>
```

And this is the class that does the validation, it works but notice that `groups` is not being used.

```
@Component
public class ObjectValidatorImpl implements ObjectValidator {
    private final Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    public ObjectValidatorImpl(final Validator validator) {
        super();
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public final <T> BindingResult getBindingResults(
               final T objectToValidate, final Class<?>...groups) {
        final DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(objectToValidate);
        binder.setValidator(validator);

        //ideally, I would like to set the groups on the binder here like
        //binder.setGroups(groups);

        binder.validate();
        return binder.getBindingResult();
    }
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the Validator to use the groups, the seems to be no method for it.

I would like to call it like this.

```
objectValidator.validate(myObject, Class1.class, Class2.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and ended up extending the SpringValidatorAdapter class so that I could perform the validation and specify the groups.

```
ExtendedSpringValidatorAdapter adapter = new ExtendedSpringValidatorAdapter(validator);
adapter.validate(objectToValidate, bindingResult, Class1.class, Class2.class);
```

Here is the definition of the extended validator:

```
package com.example.validator;

import org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;
import java.util.Set;

public class ExtendedSpringValidatorAdapter extends SpringValidatorAdapter {

    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    public ExtendedSpringValidatorAdapter(Validator targetValidator) {
        super(targetValidator);
    }

    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    // ========================================================================
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors, Class<?>... groups) {

        if (groups == null || groups.length == 0 || groups[0] == null) {
            groups = new Class<?>[]{Default.class};
        }

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> result = validate(target, groups);
        for (ConstraintViolation<Object> violation : result) {
            String field = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            FieldError fieldError = errors.getFieldError(field);
            if (fieldError == null || !fieldError.isBindingFailure()) {
                try {
                    errors.rejectValue(field,
                            violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation().annotationType().getSimpleName(),
                            getArgumentsForConstraint(errors.getObjectName(), field, violation.getConstraintDescriptor()),
                            violation.getMessage());
                } catch (NotReadablePropertyException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("JSR-303 validated property '" + field +
                            "' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - " +
                            "check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try this out Monday.

Comment: It seems a bit weird that this is not part of the default behaviour of the Validator though.

Comment: Yes, it is weird.  It might be an oversight in JSR303.  For example, the standard `@Valid` annotation doesn't take groups, but the spring `@Validated` does (at least in the newer versions).

Comment: All the validate methods on `javax.validation.Validator` have a var-args parameter taking one or more validation groups.

Comment: @Gunnar yes, but it's missing the ability to pass down a BindingResult along with the groups :(

Comment: BindingResult isn't defined by JSR 303, though.

Comment: @John, I cannot pass in my validator to `ExtendedSpringValidatorAdapter ` because it is a `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and not a `javax.validation.Validator`.  Also where do you get the `Errors errors` object from? do you create a new one like `DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(objectToValidate);` thanks

Comment: try this; BeanPropertyBindingResult bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(target, "target");

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a [SmartValidator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/SmartValidator.html). You can inject it just like a regular [Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html). By using a SmartValidator you have [Validation Hints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/SmartValidator.html#validate-java.lang.Object-org.springframework.validation.Errors-java.lang.Object...-), which you can use to pass the `javax.validation.group` as parameters. And the final code can be as simple as this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator;

@Component
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private SmartValidator validator;

    public void validate(MyObject target, Errors errors) {
        validator.validate(target, errors, FirstCheck.class, SecondCheck.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.1 version there are
`org.springframework.validation.DataBinder#validate(java.lang.Object...validationHints)`

So just do:

```
binder.validate(Class1.class, Class2.class);
```

Inside method `SmartValidator` is used:

```
if(... validator instanceof SmartValidator) {
   ((SmartValidator) validator).validate(target, bindingResult, validationHints);
```